# Spring scheduling with queue size of 1

Tags: java, spring

I am using the spring 3 Scheduling and Thread Pooling framework.  I would like to schedule different tasks at different times/intervals.  I want each task to run to completion before another task is started.

I.E.
If I have task1 and task2:
task1 runs every 10 minutes and takes 1 minute to run
task2 runs once a day and takes 5 minutes to run.

If task1 and task2 timers fire at the same time I want task1 and task2 to be put on a queue and only one task to be taken off at a time.

I know that I can setup this up with a Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, ie

```
<task:executor id="executorWithPoolSizeRange"
               pool-size="5-10"
               queue-capacity="1"/>
```

However I am not sure how to hook that executor into a scheduler.  When using a Spring ThreadPoolTaskScheduler you can only set the poolSize not the queueSize as well

```
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to use the Spring exceutor and scheduler services together to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it two ways:

One is to explicitly specify your scheduler and taskExecutor as part of the `task:annotation-driven` tag:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler"/>
```

Or as part of your scheduled task's , you can inject in the executor and submit to executor explicitly:

```
executor.execute(myrunnable/callable)
```